# Can you access the overridden Playwright configuration outside of a test?

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I have a file containing information on running a list of tests.  I need to be able to dynamically generate the path for this file, depending on a project setting.

Currently I'm attempting the following, but it only works if values are set in the global *use* section of the config file. If the value is coming from the *project*, that value is not available.

```
import config from '../../playwright.config';

test.describe('JSON Based Tests', () => {

    let tests: TestData[] = [];

    // *** how can I get the overriden project "use" section here ***
    let siteType = config.use?.siteType;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(config.use));

    if (!siteType) {
        throw new Error('siteType was not specified.');
    }

    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, `../../data/${siteType}/testData.json`);
    let fileJson = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8");

    tests = JSON.parse(fileJson);


    tests.forEach((testData) => {
        if (testData.skip)
            return;

        // validations, dataInfo and siteType are all injected via the configuration extension mechanism
        test(testData.name, async ({ validations, dataInfo, siteType }) => {
            await validations.runQuery(testData, dataInfo, siteType);
        });
    });
});
```

I know I can use environment variables, but I'd rather keep all of the configuration inside the configuration file.